# How to add the files of s3bucket folder to a zipfile and download the zip file

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a folder in s3bucket. I want to zip the files inside it and then download the zip file. Whatever i found was related to lambda. Is there a way i can do it without using lambda? if not then what is the proper way to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

S3 can't zip it on the fly for you since it's only a file storage service. You could use lambda of course, but the simplest way to download a "folder" on S3 is to use the AWS CLI.

```
aws s3 sync s3://<bucket_name>/<folder_key> <local_dest_path>
```

You can then zip it on your local machine if needed.